# When creating options for a select list programmatically- how do you add a class?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating options to append to a select list via Javascript and Dojo. What I would like to do is also add a class to each new option programatically, but every example I have seen identifies the option you want to add a class to by the ID, which I'm not sure how to add programatically either. All I know how to set for option elements is text and value.

```
for (var i = 0, idxLen = programNames.length; i < idxLen; i++) {
    var opt = domConstruct.create('option');
    //a single item in programNames looks like this: ['AR', 'Blahblahblah']
    opt.value = programNames[i][1];
    opt.text = programNames[i][1];
}
```

I want to set the class of each option to `programNames[i][0]`. Is there a way to do this?

JQuery solutions welcome.

Comment: `opt.className = programNames[i][0]`

Comment: @tymeJV Figured it was simple like that. Couldn't find it in documentation though. Thanks.

Comment: Can also do `opt.classList.add(programNames[i][0])`